# Prove the endomorphism with surjection is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.

Let $\pi_a:A \rightarrow A$ be an endomorphism defined as:

$\pi_a(x) = ax$ where $a,x \in A$ (a is fixed)

Prove that the function $\pi_a(x)$ is surjective if and only if $a$ is invertible

I have seen similar questions on this topic, but all the ones I have found deal with topics/ideas (such as modules/metric spaces) I have not studied yet. Also, I am only asking for help on the forward direction.

**My attempt** (forward direction)

Assume $\pi_a(x)$ is surjective.

Since $\pi_a(x)$ is an endomorphism and surjective, it is also injective (I haven't proved that yet)

Thus, $\pi_a(x)$ is an isomorphism $\Rightarrow$ has an inverse function (we are allowed to use this result of isomorphisms).

Thus, $\pi_a(x)$ is invertible

Side question: does this even answer the original question since we were asked to prove $a$ was invertible (I am confused here)

Comment: If the map is surjective, $1_A$ has a preimage: what can you say about it?

Comment: Ok, so the pre-image is A and the image is also A if we assume we are using $a=1_A$. I am still not sure where you are going with this.

Comment: If $\pi_a$ is surjective, that means that for *every* $y \in A$ there exists *some* $x \in A$ with $\pi_a(x) = y$. In this case, letting $y = 1_A$, we know there exists some $x \in A$ with $\pi_a(x) = 1_A$, that is: $ax = 1_A$.

Comment: Ah, I see what to do from there. Appreciate the help.

Comment: When you're done please add an answer with all the details.

Comment: Alright, posted @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.

Let $\pi_a:A\rightarrow A$ such that $\pi_a(x) = ax$ where $a$ is fixed.

Assume $\pi_a(x)$ is surjective.

Then, $\exists x \in A$ such that $\pi_a(x) = ax = 1_A$ (unity in $A$)

Since $ax=1_A$, $x$ is the inverse of $a,$ thus $a$ is inveritble.

$\Leftarrow$

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.

Let $\pi_a:A\rightarrow A$ such that $\pi_a(x) = ax$ where $a$ is fixed.

Assume $a$ is invertible.

Then, $\forall y \in A$, $\pi_a(x) = y$ when $x = a^{-1}y$ and such an $x$ exists since $y \in A$ and $a$ is invertible.